# Equivalent formulations of the Axiom of Replacement

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Let $a$, $b$, $S$ denote sets, and let $\varphi$ be a statement in two set variables. Here are two ways of expressing the Axiom of Replacement which I have seen used:

1)
If
$$\text{for all } a \in S, \text{ we have that } \exists \, b \text{ s.t. } \varphi(a,b) \text{ is true, and } \varphi(a,b) \, \& \, \varphi(a,c) \Rightarrow b = c,$$
then
$$\text{there exists } T,  \text{ such that for all }  b, \text{ we have } b \in T \, \text{iff} \, \exists \, a \in S \text{ s.t. } \varphi(a,b).$$

2) If
$$\text{for all } a \in S, \text{ we have that } \varphi(a,b) \, \& \, \varphi(a,c)\Rightarrow b = c,$$
then
$$\text{there exists } T,  \text{ such that for all }  b, \text{ we have } b \in T \, \text{iff} \, \exists \, a \in S \text{ s.t. } \varphi(a,b).$$

The first formulation seems to be the more popular one in modern books, though the second one was used in Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory. My question is whether or not these two formulations are equivalent, assuming only the axiom of extensionality as set theory background. Obviously 2) implies 1), but the converse implication is not so obviously true or false to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually we allow parameters too, do you exclude formulas with parameters, or is it simply to ease up the writing?

Comment: Simply to ease up the writing. I assumed that including parameters would not affect my question, but I could possibly be wrong about that.

Comment: Maybe it won't matter; but it's easier if you want to prove that the intersection of two sets is a set. Just use them as parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to work with the parameterised versions of (1) and (2) for simplicity.

As the following theorems show, (1) and (2) are equivalent in the presence of the empty set axiom, but they can fail to be equivalent without it.

${\bf Theorem}$ (Extensionality + Emptyset) (1) is equivalent to (2).

${\it Proof.}$ Since you've already pointed out that (2) implies (1), I'll show that (1) implies (2). Assume the antecedent of (2). There are two cases to consider. Either $\exists y\exists x\in S\phi(x, y)$ or not. If not, then:

$\{y:\exists x\in S\phi(x, y)\} = \emptyset$

and we're done. So suppose $t$ is such that $\phi(x, t)$ for some $x\in S$. Now consider the condition:

$\psi = [\exists y\phi(x, y) \to \phi(x, y)] \wedge [\neg\exists y\phi(x, y) \to y = t]$.

It is straightforward to check that $\psi$ satisfies the antecedent of (1), so we can use it to get:

$\{y: \exists x\in S\psi(x, y)\} = \{y: \exists x\in S \phi(x, y) \vee y = t\} = \{y: \exists x\in S \phi(x, y)\}$

as required. $\Box$

${\bf Theorem}$ (2) doesn't follow from the theory consisting of (1), Extensionality, Pairing, Union, Powerset, AC, and Infinity (in the form: there's a set which is injectable into a proper subset of itself).

${\it Proof}$ ${\it sketch.}$ Take a non-well-founded omega sequence $x_0 = \{x_1\} \wedge x_1 = \{x_2\},... \wedge$ $x_{n+1} = \{x_ n\}$. Then we build the cumulative hierarchy on top of it. For instance, for any $\alpha$ we let $D_{\alpha + 1}  = \mathcal P(D_\alpha)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and $D_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} D_\alpha$ for limits $\lambda$. For an inaccessible $\kappa$, it is straightforward to verify that $D_\kappa$ satisfies (1), Extensionality, Pairing, Union, Powerset, AC, and Infinity. It is also easy to see that it doesn't contain an empty set. But (2) implies the existence of an empty set. $\Box$

It's perhaps worth noting that this model also satisfies a restricted version of Separation, namely:

$\exists x\in y\cap \phi \to \{x\in y:\phi\}$ exists.

So there's a sense in which we can have all of ZFC$^-$ (i.e. ZFC - Foundation) just short of having the empty set axiom without also having (2).

${\bf Question.}$ Are there models of ZFC with the modified versions of Infinity and Separation which fail to satisfy (2)?

Comment: (1) If you have Foundation then you have to have the empty set; (2) if you have separation schema which cannot prove the existence of the empty set then something is very wrong with that schema. Maybe you want to change your question a little bit?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! Sorry for being dense, but how does the argument from Foundation to Emptyset go? I couldn't see it, partly because of the model one gets by just taking the non-well-founded omega sequence I mentioned. (If we have arbitrary replacement and infinity over a model, then we'll have Emptyset, but I didn't see how to prove the latter from the former). On (2): I know - the idea was to show, in some sense, that Empty set is both necessary and sufficient for (2).

Comment: If $x$ is the empty set, we're done. Otherwise there is some $y\in x$ such that $x\cap y$ is empty. Since with parameters the replacement schemas can define intersections, we're done.

Comment: So, I'm taking Replacement in the form of (1). But that's satisfied in the model I mentioned. So, unless I've fudged something, Extensionality, Foundation, and Replacement won't imply intersections.

Comment: $\varphi(x,y,p):=(x=y)\land(y\in p)$.

Comment: Yea, but unless $S$ only contains things in $p$, this won't satisfy the antecedent of (1). That is, it won't be true in general that for any $x\in S$ there's a $y$ such that $\phi(x, y,p)$.